# CSS not firing on html template in backbone project

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, require

I have a backbone project using text! plugin of require.js. Here is my home view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
       "underscore" ,
       "backbone" ,
       "text!templates/Home/Dep.html"], fucntion($ , _ , Backbone , DepartmentList){

        var depList = _.template(DepartmentList);   
        var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

           //........

        render : function(){
            $("#navbody").html(depList);
        }
}
```

Here is `Dep.html` :

```
<ul id="dropdown-menu">
<%
   var depList = new Navigator();
   _.each(depList.getTopDepartment(18),function(department){
%>
    <li data-submenu-id="submenu-1">
      <a href="#"><%=department.DepartmentName%></a>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

I have include `home.css` in HomeView, the others html elements are working, except the elements come from `Dep.html`.

Is it because the DOM element of `Dep.html` not yet create when HomeView loaded? If so, how can I do.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you..

Comment: @muistooshort It was my bad typo.

Comment: Load order doesn't affect CSS rendering.  Can you post the markup that results from your app along with the styles that aren't being applied?

Comment: What do you mean by 'CSS not firing' can you elaborate more on what is the exact problem?

Comment: When I viewed `Home` page source code, CSS file was including, but `<ul id="dropdown-menu">.....</ul>` was not show in the source code, the otherwise, it was shown in the webpage.